# Dropbox ios sync api : readData don't wait

Tags: ios, synchronization, dropbox

I am using `readData` to sync a zip file with the server but the program doesn't wait for the download of the change in zip. Here's my code:

```
enter DBPath *newPath = [[DBPath root] childPath:@"decoupe.zip"];
DBError *dbError;
DBFile *dbFile = [[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] openFile:newPath    error:nil];
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [dbFile readHandle:&dbError];
NSData *fileData = [dbFile readData:&readError];
[fileData writeToFile:@"/Users/walid/Documents/ikksTestSynchAPI/ikksTestSynchAPI/decoupe.zip" atomically:YES]; here
```

The execution doesn't wait for the download of a new zip file, but if I run my program 2 or 3 times the new zip file is downloaded and the change in size of the zip file is effected.

**How can I ensure the program waits for the download?**

Answer (score 0):

In the Sync API, all reads operate on cached copies of the files (when a cached version exists). To update to the newest version of the file, you need to open the file, set up an observer to be notified when the file changes, wait for the `isCached` flag to be true on the file's sync status, and then call `update` to update to the newest version of the file.

See [the "observers" section of the iOS tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/ios#observers) for an example.

Comment: thank you for your answer, before continuing I would like to know if the sync API uses the binary diff to download the files, I feel that whenever it downloads the whole file

Comment: No, the Dropbox API in general doesn't support any sort of diff-based upload/download. Full files are always transferred.

Comment: disappointment that the API does not make binay diff. in this case I'll unzip my html directory and try to synchronize. I add this code                            DBPath *rootPath = [[DBPath root] childPath:@""];
      [filesystem addObserver:self forPathAndChildren:rootPath block:^() {
        
        NSLog(@"something changed in your dropbox folder!");
    }];            , 
it works fine but how do you know which file was changed to download

Comment: Unfortunately, the Sync API doesn't expose a way to see which paths changed. If you have the files open, you can observe each file directly.

Comment: I have a huge number of files and subfolders, this is a catalog application, but small changes can happens in every moment, update two files or add five files... can this do job : https://github.com/chrishulbert/CHBgDropboxSync but the sdk is version 1

Comment: I think i can wait the download with : while (!dbFile.newerStatus.cached)

                {

                    

                   [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];

                  

                    NSLog(@"sleep ");

              }    can i wait the DBFileSystem to download the metadata in the begin of program, because the download not fired at the first run, i suppose this because the DBFileSystem not have the information(of file updated in dropbox)  yet

Answer (score 0):

I think i can wait the download with : `while (!dbFile.newerStatus.cached) { [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f]; NSLog(@"sleep "); }`    can i wait the DBFileSystem to download the metadata in the begin of program, because the download not fired at the first run, i suppose this because the DBFileSystem not have the information(of file updated in dropbox) yet